# GotKeyboardFocus event from child to parent window

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have an application which must open an on screen keyboard whenever certain UIElements gain focus (TextBox, PasswordBox etc). I use the GotKeyboardFocus and LostKeyboardFocus on the MainWindow to achieve this:

```
this.GotKeyboardFocus += AutoKeyboard.GotKeyboardFocus;
this.LostKeyboardFocus += AutoKeyboard.LostKeyboardFocus;
```

Everything is fine, except when I open a new window which contains TextBoxes of its own. Obviously, as they are not part of the MainWindows routedEvent they do not fire the keyboard focus events. Is there a way that I can either have all child windows inherit GotKeyboardFocus from the MainWindow or have it pass keyboard focus events back to its parent?

Comment: When creating the child window, why don't you: `childWindow.GotKeyboardFocus += AutoKeyboard.GotKeyboardFocus;`

Comment: I've done that for the most part but there are two main issues. The first is that there are a lot of child windows throughout the application. Adding that line to them all is possible and if it's the only solution I'll do it. The bigger issue is that some of our windows use usercontrols from other libraries. Some of these controls open their own windows which are private and we aren't allowed to alter the code in these libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use *EventManager* in order to register global (application wide) handlers for selected events. Here is an example:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(
            typeof (UIElement),             
            UIElement.GotKeyboardFocusEvent,
            new RoutedEventHandler(GotKeyboardFocusEventHandler));

        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(
            typeof (UIElement), 
            UIElement.LostKeyboardFocusEvent,
            new RoutedEventHandler(LostKeyboardFocusEventHandler));
    }

    private void GotKeyboardFocusEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
       ...
    }

    private void LostKeyboardFocusEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution! I can't believe I didn't come across this in my hours searching. You've saved me a lot of work. I was about to give in and add the event every time I created a new window. Thanks.